# How to print as many vectors as the user asks? java

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I've just started with my programming course and I have a question. I need to print some random vectors and then perform some actions with them, but the problem is that the number of vectors and their dimensions should be defined by a user. I was able to print vectors with the dimensions that the user wants, but the number of vektors was defind by me. How do I print the number of vectors that the user wants?

```java
Vector v1, v2, v3;
v1 = new Vector(in.nextInt());
v2 = new Vector(in.nextInt());
v3 = new Vector(in.nextInt());

v1.input();
v1.output();
v2.input();
v2.output();
v3.input();
v3.output();
```

```java
public class Vector {
    private int dim;
    private int[] vec;

    Vector(int dimn) {
        dim = dimn;
        vec = new int[dim];

    }

    public void input(){
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
            vec[i] = (int) (Math.random() *50-30);
        }
    }

    public void output() {
        System.out.print("Vector ");
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
            System.out.printf(" %4d",vec[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Loop/User Input from Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720662/java-loop-user-input-from-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int noOfVectors = in.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < noOfVectors; i++) {
    Vector v = new Vector(in.nextInt());
    v.input();
    v.output();
}
```